# how to get output from a transaction?

Tags: node.js, ethereum

when I tried to get receipt from a transaction, i got:

```
{ blockHash: '0x427cd61bf60e57f2070afdc7956bd21ff9a8b98a2bzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz',
  blockNumber: 2320zzzz,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 219zz,
  from: '0xc0536ed5373ede78f3295e1zzzzzzzzzzzzz',
  gasUsed: 21965,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  status: '0x1',
  to: '0x556fa8e57cf99e697cbf2f667zzzzz',
  transactionHash: '0x67d55fe2b99216806ebf7cebb471649f1477429czzzzzzzzzzz',
  transactionIndex: 0 }
```

but what I see in remix-ide is:

```
status  0x1 Transaction mined and execution succeed
 from   0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c
 to     test.thu() 0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a
 gas    3000000 gas

 transaction cost   21965 gas 
 execution cost     693 gas 
 input  0xd9b002aa
 decoded input  {}
 decoded output     {
    "0": "string: thanh cong"
}
 logs   []
 value  0 wei
```

certainly, I expect output from my function, how can I do it? tks.

Comment: Have you already found the answer?

Comment: I guess there is no way to do it. what I saw in remix-ide might just be what self-calculated by the ide.